# How to call realtime streaming method from another class

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I need to centralize the calls to my realtime streaming Firebase database within a class, and call those methods from another class. The method is intended to 'listen' to the node within Firebase and then post to the application log upon updates.

However, my present setup notes it being synchronous and upon application run, returns null. How can I make this setup work?

TestFirebaseActions actions streaming class, method:

```
String output;
public async Task<String> realtimeStreamTest()
{
    var observable = firebase
      .Child("driver_rate")
        .AsObservable<DriverRate>()
        .Subscribe(d => output = d.Object.driversRate);

    return output;
}
```

Calling method and attempting to "listen" from another class:

```
public async void firebaseRealStreamTestMethod()
{

    TestFirebaseActions testFirebase = new TestFirebaseActions();

    Task<String> contentsTask = testFirebase.realtimeStreamTest();

    // await! control returns to the caller and the task continues to run on another thread
    string contents = await contentsTask;

    Log.Verbose("firebaseRealStreamTestMethod()", contents);

}
```

How can I create and call to allow for asynchronous listening on this observable from within another class?

Comment: your `firebaseRealStreamTestMethod` is `async void`, not `async Task`

Comment: Yes,  because it is intended to post to the log, see the last line in the method

Comment: Maybe you should use `TaskCompletionSource` instead of `IOnservable`, or call the `OnNext` on `IObservable`